# Add DLL programmatically at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Using C#, I create a DLL at runtime and now I want to add it as a reference to my project at runtime.

I tried using the `LoadFrom` method, but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: what is your need to create/add dll at run-time?

Comment: How are you creating a DLL at run-time?

Comment: You want to add the reference to the VS project at runtime? Makes no sense.

Comment: This question is nonsense.  You cannot dynamically create an assembly at runtime and use its types before you start the program.  That requires a time machine.

Comment: I have two exe. first one change the dll and then the second exe run and use that dll . the second exe has the previous version of dll . and I want to reload it in load event of second exe , and then run it

Comment: > Starting with .NET Framework 4, the ability to execute code in assemblies loaded from remote locations is disabled by default, and the call to the LoadFrom method throws a FileLoadException.  
from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#overloads

Answer (score 26):

First you should load the dll

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("dllPath");
```

Then you may need to add the assembly to the app domain

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
```

After that you can load any type from this assembly

```
Type t = assembly.GetType("typeName");
```

Then using reflection you can execute methods on this type

Note that you may need to add the below in the configuration file.

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="dlls folder"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: thanks Ghyath Serhal, would you please explain it more? where can I change My configuration

Comment: First What is your application, is it an web application, windows application, windows service?

Comment: Look, each application has an appdomain assosiated with it.In order to access a dll in a certain application, you should add the dll to its appdomain. When you add a dll to the appdomain, you cannot update it or remove it, and you cannot add the dll many time to the appdomain. Hence, the solution is whenever you change something in the dll, you should create a new dll, you can simply change it is name. after creating the new dll, you can load it, add it to the appdomain and use it.

Comment: I faced the same problem one time, each time I change something in the dll, i create a new dll, and append a guid to its name. In this way i can add the dll to the appdomain and use the new dll updates. Please address exactly what is not clear for you in order for me to help you.

Comment: thanks Ghyath Serhal for your answers . but it dosent work. because my codes was wroten deppend on the name of a fist dll. I think I should search for another way.

Answer (score 9):

**LoadFile vs. LoadFrom**

> Be careful - these aren't the same
>   thing.
>
> LoadFrom() goes through Fusion and can
>   be redirected to another assembly at a
>   different path but with that same
>   identity if one is already loaded in
>   the LoadFrom context. LoadFile()
>   doesn't bind through Fusion at all -
>   the loader just goes ahead and loads
>   exactly* what the caller requested. It
>   doesn't use either the Load or the
>   LoadFrom context. So, LoadFrom()
>   usually gives you what you asked for,
>   but not necessarily. LoadFile() is for
>   those who really, really want exactly
>   what is requested. (*However, starting
>   in v2, policy will be applied to both
>   LoadFrom() and LoadFile(), so
>   LoadFile() won't necessarily be
>   exactly what was requested. Also,
>   starting in v2, if an assembly with
>   its identity is in the GAC, the GAC
>   copy will be used instead. Use
>   ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() to load
>   exactly what you want - but, note that
>   assemblies loaded that way can't be
>   executed.)
>
> LoadFile() has a catch. Since it
>   doesn't use a binding context, its
>   dependencies aren't automatically
>   found in its directory. If they aren't
>   available in the Load context, you
>   would have to subscribe to the
>   AssemblyResolve event in order to bind
>   to them.

ref [Suzanne Cook's .NET CLR Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Use [Assembly.LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) method and then run code inside it using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `Assembly.Load` is [usually what you'd want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058617/load-assembly-doesnt-worked-correctly/4058654#4058654), not `LoadFrom` and not `LoadFile`:

> Which context is right for you? In
>   general, I strongly recommend that you
>   use the Load context whenever possible

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add dll to a project when project is already running. However, you can load the dll using Assembly.LoadFrom( filename). Normally such scenerio is used for SOA or plugin based projects. You can use interface to specify the type structure and load the dll and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx) method to dynamically load an assembly at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple in .NET:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx